# Nifi: Can I do mathematical operations on a json file values?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON file as an input to a processor. Something like this:

```
{"x" : 10, "y" : 5}
```

Can I do mathematical operations on these values instead of writing a custom processor? I need to do something like

```
( x / y ) * 3
```

^ Just an example.

I need to save the result to an output file.

UPDATE:
This is my text in generateFlowFile processor:

```
X|Y
1|123
2|111
```

And this is my AVRO schema:

```
{
 "name": "myschema",
 "namespace": "nifi",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
 {"name": "X" , "type": "int"},
 {"name": "Y" , "type": "int"} ]
}
```

When I change the above types to string, it works fine but I cannot perform math operations on a string.

FYI, I have selected 'Use Schema Name Property' in Schema Access Strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QueryRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) processor.

- Configure/enable **Record Reader/Writer** controller services
- Define Avro schema to `read` the incoming Json.
- Define Avro Schema to `write` the results of query in desired format.

Add new property in the query record processor as

**sql**

```
select  ( x / y ) * 3 as div from FLOWFILE
```

The **output flowfile** from the **query record processor** will be in the configured Record Writer format.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried the same but I get an error when the field type is "int" in the schema. Error is : Failed to read next record in input for 'x' due to For input string:'x'. And this is happening only for type int or long. But if I change to string and have the sql as `selct * from FLOWFILE` , it works fine.

Comment: @NoName, I think the issue is coming with `Avro Schema`, please update your question with `sample data` and `Reader/Writer Avro schema` that you are using now. So that i will try to help u to fix the issue...!!

Comment: @NoName, I tried with your `sample records` and uploaded template here: https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/Division_QueryRecord.xml **upload this template to your instance** and change the avro schema as per your case.